# android studio error says no installed build tools, but they are installed?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I installed Android Studio and also installed the build tools under
Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools tab > 33.0.2 Installed

The attached picture shows it's installed along with the error. I have tried to use File > Invalidate Caches (all) but it also didn't work.

I can also go into my Android/Sdk/build-tools/ and see 33.0.2 is there. All the files are in the folder and look like the other ones.

Android Studio bug?

[image]